# List<String> mapping in Hibernate on object with composite key

Tags: hibernate

A very simple questions.
I have a class which represents an order

Given the following mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Order" table="hbmOrder">
    <composite-id name="key">
        <key-property name="OrderStatus" type="string" />
        <key-property name="OrderType" type="string" />
        <key-property name="version" type="integer" />
        <key-property name="orderId" type="string" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="ccy" type="string" />
```

I'd like to add a new property which is an un-ordered list of Strings to hold a list of sales people. There can be zero, one, or many sales people.

```
List<String> salesPersons;
```

This has so far defeated me. My best attempt so far is:

```
    <list name="salesPersons" table="order_salesPersons">
        <key column="key" />
        <list-index column="index" />
        <many-to-many column="order_id" class="java.lang.string" />
    </list>
```

This isn't working because:

1. it is a many-to-many mapping (I guess it should be a one to many)
2. The class `java.lang.string` is not supported by Hibernate?

Also, due to project restrictions which are beyond my control I cannot use annotations.

Most of the example I can find on the next deal with much more complex examples. Again, if anyone can point me in the direction of a simple example that will be  a big help!

Answer (score 2):

instead of many-to-many use element:

```
<element column="order_id" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks. I think that's half the problem. But the other issue is the key for the hbmOrder table has four columns, so the <key column="key" /> fails.